# php http facebook api GET notation

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, get-request

I don't understand this notation for GET requests in Facebook's documentation (found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)):

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
     client_id={app-id}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &grant_type=client_credentials
```

What does this mean in apache terms and how to I write a request like this in php? I've found both `file_get_contents` and `http_get` which require a url. Syntax like this:

```
$response = http_get("http://www.example.com/", array("timeout"=>1), $info);
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/')
```

Could I use either or both of these functions? How would I write it? I'm having a bugger of a time finding good documentation on this.

Comment: `GET /foo` is just how the actual http request looks, and is what your browser would do if you had `http://example.com/foo`. they've also split it into multiple lines for legibility, that's all.

Comment: Gotcha. So I could send the request this way: `file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&grant_type=client_credentials')`

Comment: @Marc B: Thank you for tolerating a beginner's question! Couldn't find anything online about this. Hopefully this will be a help to another beginner in the future.

Comment: did you put in your client ip/secret? or did you literally use `{app-id}` and `{app-secret}`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Please post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Marc B: Removed my previous comment about getting an error. No I entered my `app-id` and `app-secret`. Forgot to remove the brackets. dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Marc B:

> GET /foo is just how the actual http request looks, and is what your browser would do if you had http://example.com/foo. they've also split it into multiple lines for legibility, that's all.

This worked:

```
file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app‌​-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&grant_type=client_credentials')
```

Remember to remove the curly braces in app-id and app-secret.